# Pass arguments between qt process?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application, say application A.
During A's running, I want to start another process, say application B.
So I use the following:

```
QProcess::start("appB.exe","argumentsABC");
```

I can now start the application B successfully,
but in application B, how can I handle the arguments passed in from application A(like simply qDebug() it out on the terminal)?

Simple examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process is started as if was launched from the command line. You just have to print them out in `int main( int argh, char *argv[])` as usual.

Comment: @Nyaruko, using your call, argh here will be 1, since you passed one argument, and the first value in argv will be "argumentsABC"

Comment: Thank you, but how to print the argv contents out? as I dont know its length?

Comment: @Nyaruko Each argument is a zero terminated string. You can just print them with `qDebug() << argv[i]`